# Maximal derangements

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

When one shuffles playing cards, the goal is evidently to achieve a possibly big derangement
of a given deck. For manual shuffling there are terms like inshuffle, outshuffle etc. I like
to know whether there is a sensible general measure of derangements of n objects and
efficient algorithm to compute that measure and eventually also to determine the set representing maximal derangements.

Comment: I don't think talking about the "most unsorted" permutation makes sense. You would still want the sorted permutation to be possible, after all. I think you want to look into the related probability theory; the ideal shuffling method ensures a uniform probability over all permutations. That said, you might want to look into measures of *sortedness*, e.g. [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29) or number of consecutive runs.

Comment: The [Kendall tau distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) might be of some use; it's the total number of discordant pairs.

Comment: There is also a great StackOverflow post about [efficient algorithms to determine how sorted a list is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206617/efficiently-determine-how-sorted-a-list-is-eg-levenshtein-distance).

Answer (score 5):

I second Raphael's remark that when shuffling cards, you don't want the deck to be "unsorted", but rather random. However, when analyzing any specific shuffle, there can be measures of randomness that can be used to *prove* that a small number of shuffles isn't enough to make the deck random enough.

As a simple example, consider the "top card shuffle", in which you repeatedly take the top card and place it at an arbitrary location. If you don't repeat this enough times, then the top $k$ cards will retain their relative order (since you never put the top card somewhere among the top $k$ cards). So a reasonable measure of "sortedness" would be the maximal $k$ such that the top $k$ cards retain their relative order - for a shuffled deck, we expect this to be very small.

There is a similar measure for riffle shuffle, namely the number of *ascents*, two adjacent cards which retain their relative order. A random permutation has $n/2$ ascents, while an (under-)riffle-shuffled deck will have too many.

All this and more is described in [David Aldous and Persi Diaconis, *Shuffling cards and stopping times*](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/aldous86.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Although Yuval Filmus' answer addresses the question behind the question, and comments partially answer the explicit question, there are other parts of the explicit question which remain unanswered by previous comments and answers.

> I like to know whether there is a sensible general measure of derangements of n objects

As previously mentioned in comments, the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29) is a general measure of how out-of-order a permutation is.

> and efficient algorithm to compute that measure

There is a standard algorithm to compute it in $\Theta(n \lg n)$ by adapting mergesort.

> and eventually also to determine the set representing maximal derangements.

The reversed permutation. And *this* is the big reason why, as Yuval Filmus says (in different words), the aim is to maximise entropy rather than to maximise the derangement. A reverse-ordered deck of cards is just as bad as an ordered deck of cards when it comes to playing games with it.

Answer (score 0):

I am a total noob, but as I try to get some C++ chops in order before Data Structures and Algorithms Class this Fall I wrote a super easy disorder function in a Class named Array which generates int arrays filled with randomly generated numbers:

```
void Array::disorder() {
    double disorderValue = 0;
    int counter = this->arraySize;
    for (int n = 0; n < this->arraySize; n++) {
        disorderValue += abs(((n + 1) - array[n]));
//      cout << "disorderValue variable test value = " << disorderValue << endl;
        counter++;
    }
    cout << "Disorder Value = " << (disorderValue / this->arraySize) / (this->arraySize / 2) << "\n" << endl;
}
```

Simply compares the value in each element to the index of the element + 1 so that an array in reverse order has a disorder value of 1, and a sorted array has a disorder value of 0. Not sophisticated, but working.

Michael

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to two different questions! Instead, mention your answer as a comment in one of the posts.